# Accessing command line arguments in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I am trying to make my setups scripts modular. I am calling setup exe's from within main setup script based to the requirements. I want to pass command line arguments to the exe being called. Can someone please tell me how to access the command line arguments in the script being called.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23):

you can use `GetOptions` function (`FileFunc.nsh` must be included above). Following example shows `p` parameter reading; its value is saved into the variable. `$CMDLINE` is your command line (absolute or relative, as you called) containing also your parameters.

```
!include FileFunc.nsh

Var variable    
${GetOptions} $CMDLINE "/p" $variable
```

Comment: Just to define ' Var variable' before the call.

Comment: Use `GetParameters` instead of `$CMDLINE`, as the latter contains the exe name which can get in the way. See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4134496/2604492).

Answer (score 1):

Try to get options from Command line by their name:
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Get_command_line_parameter_by_name

Comment: Didn't work for me, was happy to find the accepted answer.