# Trying to add command-line argument execution to NSIS installer

Tags: installation, command-line-arguments, nsis

I am trying to customize the NSIS installer. Based on an option from the user, I would like the program to run with a different option, which I would set up with a command line option.

(I save some files that I delete at the end, and if the user doesn't want to proceed with the install, then I want to run the utility with the option -d that only deletes temporary files.)

I have found this post: [Accessing command line arguments in NSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185982/accessing-command-line-arguments-in-nsis) but I don't know how to set it up to run a program with a command-line argument.

This is what I am trying:
I tried:

```
SetOutPath "$TEMP"
!define MY_FILE "file.exe -d"
File /nonfatal "${MY_FILE}"
ExecWait '"$TEMP\${MY_FILE}" 
Delete /REBOOTOK "$TEMP\${MY_FILE}"
```

I got a warning that it didn't find `file.exe -d`.

So I am trying something like

```
$(GetOptions) $CMDLINE "/d" $Trying_This
;Not sure what to put to get the program
```

I am still experimenting with NSIS, it is a huge challenge, and can't find an example to guide me.

Note: I am running the file with no options, and then I want NSIS to insert the option -d (or other options like -f filename)

**Edit:** I had incomplete code in the post... I had the ExecWait in real life...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Outfile test.exe
requestexecutionlevel user
InstallDir "$Temp\Test" ;Default $InstDir
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

page directory
page instfiles

section 
StrCpy $1 "/Foo"
ClearErrors
${GetOptions} $CMDLINE "-d" $0
${IfNot} ${Errors} 
    StrCpy $1 "/Bar"
${EndIF}
SetOutPath $InstDir
File "File.exe" ;Extracting to $InstDir
ExecWait '"$InstDir\File.exe" $1' ;Calling with /Foo or if installer was started with -d; /Bar 
sectionend
```

Comment: If file.exe is only used during setup you should probably not extract it to $instdir, you should call Initpluginsdir and then extract it to $pluginsdir

Answer (score 1):

The `File` statement makes NSIS include the given file into the compressed data, and at run time it will be placed into the current working directory (that you can change with `SetOutPath`). It won't let you execute an executable, with or without parameter.

If you want to run an executable during installation, you must 1) include the exe and 2) execute it at runtime, with possibly changing to a temp directory e.g. if the executable is an installer.

```
!define MY_FILE "file.exe"
!define MY_ARGS "-d"
SetOutPath "$TEMP" 
File "${MY_FILE}"
ExecWait '$TEMP\${MY_FILE} ${MY_ARGS}' $0   ;$0 will get the return code
${if} $0 <> 0
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "Sorry, but the installation returned the code $0.$\n \
         Cannot continue the installation." /SD IDOK
    Abort
${endif}
Delete "$TEMP\${MY_FILE}"
```

Of course if you need to keep the exe after do not go to the temp directory nor delete the executable at the end.