# Passing parameters to NSIS from Ant

Tags: ant, nsis

I have an existing Ant script that calls MakeNSIS and successfully creates an installer file.  I want the output path to be changed within Ant, and then passed along to NSIS.  Currently, I have tried calling NSIS in this way:

```
    <exec executable="${nsis_exe.dir}/makensis.exe">
        <arg value="${installer.dir}/installer.nsi" />
        <arg value="/DTEST=myvalue"/>
        <arg value="/DBUILD_VERSION_LABEL=${build.version.label}"/>
    </exec>
```

But I have not been able to retrieve this value in the nsi file.  I cannot use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185982/accessing-command-line-arguments-in-nsis) solution because I want to use the parameter in the File command, which requires a symbol, not a variable, to work correctly.

I'm using the following in my nsi file:

```
DetailPrint ${TEST}
DetailPrint ${DTEST}
DetailPrint ${BUILD_VERSION_LABEL}
File /r "C:\DTU\Build\${BUILD_VERSION_LABEL}\*"
```

And the  errors I receive are:

```
[exec] warning: unknown variable/constant "{TEST}" detected, ignoring (../Solution/third_party/NSIS_Build/dtu_installer.nsi:184)
[exec] DetailPrint: "${TEST}"
[exec] warning: unknown variable/constant "{DTEST}" detected, ignoring (../Solution/third_party/NSIS_Build/dtu_installer.nsi:185)
[exec] DetailPrint: "${DTEST}"
[exec] warning: unknown variable/constant "{BUILD_VERSION_LABEL}" detected, ignoring (../Solution/third_party/NSIS_Build/dtu_installer.nsi:186)
[exec] DetailPrint: "${BUILD_VERSION_LABEL}"
[exec] File: Returning to: "C:\DTU\Build\${BUILD_VERSION_LABEL}"
[exec] File: "C:\DTU\Build\${BUILD_VERSION_LABEL}\*" -> no files found.
```

Any ideas what I could use or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I had was the order of my arguments.  I had the following in my ANT script:

```
<exec executable="${nsis_exe.dir}/makensis.exe">
        <arg value="${installer.dir}/installer.nsi" />
        <arg value="/DTEST=myvalue"/>
        <arg value="/DBUILD_VERSION_LABEL=${build.version.label}"/>
</exec>
```

But apparently I cannot see the /D parameters in the nsi file this way.  If I change it so the nsi file is the last parameter, it works:

```
<exec executable="${nsis_exe.dir}/makensis.exe">
        <arg value="/DTEST=myvalue"/>
        <arg value="/DBUILD_VERSION_LABEL=${build.version.label}"/>
        <arg value="${installer.dir}/installer.nsi" />
</exec>
```

Then I can access the parameters in the nsi file as I was:

```
DetailPrint ${TEST}
DetailPrint ${BUILD_VERSION_LABEL}
File /r "C:\DTU\Build\${BUILD_VERSION_LABEL}\*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ant properties don't work outside of the `build.xml` file. If you want these values in your `nsi` file you can create a template file, and then copy that template file to your `nsi` while using `<filterset/>` and `<filter/>` entities. This will replace the parameters with the values you've specified:

#### nsi Template File

```
DetailPrint @TEST@
DetailPrint @DTEST@
DetailPrint @BUILD_VERSION_LABEL@
File /r "C:\DTU\Build\@BUILD_VERSION_LABEL@\*"
```

Then copy over your `nsi` template like this:

```
<copy file="${NSI.TEMPLATE.DIR}/${NSI.TEMPLATE.FILE}"
     tofile="${NSI.DIR}/${NSI.FILE}">
     <filterset>
         <filter token="TEST"                 value="${TEST}"/>
         <filter token="DTEST"                value="${DTEST}"/>
         <filter token="BUILD_VERSION_LABEL"  value="${BUILD_VERSION_LABEL}"/>
     </filterset>
</copy>
```

Now, you can execute your command using the newly copied `nsi` file. Make sure you've defined your various Ant properties such as `${TEST}` and `${DTEST}`.

---

## Addendum

You can use `<concat/>` to build your file. It might be easier because you won't need to first create a template, and then copy the template with `<filterset>`:

```
<target name="build.nsi.file">
    <concat destfile="${NSI.file}">DetailPrint ${TEST}
DetailPrint ${DTEST}
DetailPrint ${BUILD_VERSION_LABEL}
File /r "C:\DTU\Build\${BUILD_VERSION_LABEL}\*"
</concat>
</target>
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but I was hoping for something cleaner.  Are command line arguments inaccessible in the NSI file?

Comment: The command line arguments are passed to Ant for execution, and if the parameter begins with `-D`, are considered Ant properties which are unavailable outside of Ant's Java execution. You can pass them as parameters as you were doing, or you can use `<filterset/>` to replace tokens in a file. You can also use `<concat>` to build your file from scratch. This way, you don't have to have a template file. See Addendum above.

Comment: Actually, I was referring to the command line arguments passed to makensis.exe.  If I pass -D arguments to makensis, how can I access these in the NSI file?

Comment: You can't except by building the `makensis.exx` command like you do and passing them as `/D` parameters to that command. You had that in your OP. Then, it's up to NSI to use the `/D` parameters in that `nsi` file.